# C++ subclass constructor is ignored

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

In the following code, when I initialize a subclass with an argument of the same class, the program calls the parent class constructor but not the subclass's [derived3]. However, if I pass in an argument belonging to just the parent class, it calls both functions correctly [derived2]. Why would the compiler ignore the subclass constructor in the former case?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Base(Base& b) {
        std::cout << "Base parameterized constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Derived(Base& b) : Base(b) {
        std::cout << "Derived parameterized constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "[base]" << std::endl;
    Base base {};
    std::cout << "[derived]" << std::endl;
    Derived derived {};

    std::cout << "[base2]" << std::endl;
    Base base2 {base};
    std::cout << "[derived2]" << std::endl;
    Derived derived2 {base};
    
    std::cout << "[base3]" << std::endl;
    Base base3 {derived};
    std::cout << "[derived3]" << std::endl;
    Derived derived3 {derived};
}
```

Output:

> [base]
> Base constructor
> [derived]
> Base constructor
> Derived constructor
> [base2]
> Base parameterized constructor
> [derived2]
> Base parameterized constructor
> Derived parameterized constructor
> [base3]
> Base parameterized constructor
> [derived3]
> Base parameterized constructor

Comment: You are calling the compiler-generated copy constructor, not any of the constructors you have explicitly defined.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
Derived derived3 {derived};
```

You are making a copy, so the copy constructor is called.  Since you did not override the copy constructor with your own that prints a statement, you only see the base copy constructor get called.

Adding

```
Derived(Derived& d) : Base(d) {
    std::cout << "Derived copy constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

will give you two print statements for the derived3 line.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Base(Base& b)` is not a regular parameterized constructor. It's a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

This is a special type of constructor and is handled specially. `derived3` calls both `Derived` copy constructor (implicitly declared by compiler) and `Base` copy constructor (declared by you).